Getting GDAL to work with GeoServer
I am looking for advice on getting GDAL to work with my GeoServer 2.25.3.
I recently installed GDAL 3.X.X via Homebrew. I have configured my environment variable as needed, but I cannot find the extension in my GeoServer.
How can I do this?
This is my environment variable
export GDAL_DATA=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/3.9.1_1/share/gdal
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/3.9.1_1/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.library.path=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/3.9.1_1/lib"

And this is the error on my log when i run geoserver with startup.sh

Native library load failed. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
gdalalljni in java.library.path:
[/Users/andriniaina/Library/Java/Extensions, /Library/Java/Extensions,
/Network/Library/Java/Extensions, /System/Library/Java/Extensions,
/usr/lib/java, .] juil. 27, 2024 10:57:09 PM
it.geosolutions.imageio.gdalframework.GDALUtilities loadGDAL WARNING:
Failed to load the GDAL native libs. This is not a problem unless you
need to use the GDAL plugins: they won't be enabled.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.AllRegister()V

I precis "I Use Macbook Air M1 with OS sonoma"
